# Error : could not find function "ImportMethodFrom"

Tags: r, classification, data-mining

I tried to run the code in Chapter 7 Data mining with R learning with case study book but I got an error in following line:

```
rankWorkflows(svm, maxs = TRUE)
```

The error was:

> Error in as.character.default(X[[i]], ...) :    no method for coercing
>   this S4 class to a vector

Then I searched on the internet and found following solution:

```
importMethodsFrom(GenomicRanges, as.data.frame)
```

and again again I got a new error:

> Error: could not find function "importMethodFrom"

I searched a lot but I got nothing :(

Comment: you are likely missing the library where `importMethodFrom` is located

Comment: yeah I know but I dont know the name of the library,I couldnt find it

Comment: Isn't `importMethodsFrom` only used in `NAMESPACE` files? Try loading the whole `GenomicRanges` library using `library(GenomicRanges)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `library(sos)` to find the packages where your function is located.

```
library(sos)
findFn("replaceherewithyourfunction")
```

Comment: I got this message: download of package ‘sos’ failed

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Bea, there does not seem to be a `importMethodsFrom` anywhere in `R`. My guess is you found the call in a `NAMESPACE` file. Those files have different syntax than normal R scripts.

If you want to load a specific function from an R package (rather than all functions from a package), you can use `libraryname::functionname` instad of `functionname` in your code. In your case, replace `as.data.frame` with `GenomicRanges::as.data.frame`

If this does not work (for example because you don't have `as.data.frame` anywhere in your code), you can also load the whole `GenomicRanges` library with `library(GenomicRanges)`

Comment: I found this message: standardGeneric for "as.data.frame" defined from package "BiocGenerics"

function (x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...) 
standardGeneric("as.data.frame")
<environment: 0x000000000c0c2410>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("as.data.frame")  for currently available ones.

Comment: Have you tried loading the library with `library(GenomicRanges)` before calling `rankWorkflows`?